# QRCode Not Working with React.Js

Tags: reactjs, qr-code

I have just started coding with ReactJs and am trying to create my first QR Code using ReactJS. I am unable to do so.
I have taken a sample of some code from GitHub and trying to implement but it's not working. I have also installed `qrcode-react` package with the following command:

```
npm install qrcode-react
```

and this is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="React.min.js"></script>
<script src="JSXTransformer.js"></script>


<script type="text/jsx">
/** @jsx React.DOM */
var React = require('react');
var QRCode = require('qrcode.react');

React.render(
<QRCode value="http://facebook.github.io/react/" />,
mountNode
);
</script>

<img src="qrcode.png" height="256" width="256"/>
</body>
</html>
```

What I see in chrome dev. tools:

```
referenceError: require is not defined
```

What am I missing?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You need to transpile your code if you want to use `require`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you hosting the referenced scripts in an express server? Or are you using a bundling mechanism like webpack?

You would need to bundle the QRCode scripts and reference them to run the example. Take a look at how the Makefile is bundling all the necessary scripts together - https://github.com/zpao/qrcode.react. This URL by the way has a complete working example which you should analyze.

Comment: @Jatinder You should read up on it. Check out [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) or [browserify](http://browserify.org/).

Comment: Hi ,It is still not working.I have done the following so far:-

Comment: 1)opened node command editor and traversed to my folder.
2)executed the following command:
 1)npm install browserify
 2)npm install require
 a folder by the name node_modules gets created with two sub folders namely .bin and .require
3)i execute 
 browserify main.js -o bundle.js
4)Add the following tag to my HTML file
 <script src='bundle.js'></script>
btw this is the code of my main.js library:-
<script type='text/jsx'>
var React = require('react');
var QRCode = require('qrcode.react');

React.render(
  <QRCode value="http://facebook.github.io/react/" />,
  mountNode
);
</script>
 error@step3

Comment: The easiest way would be to clone the QR Code example and analyze it.

Answer (score 0):

```
1)opened node command editor and traversed to my folder.
2)executed the following command:
    1)npm install browserify
    2)npm install require
    a folder by the name node_modules gets created with two sub folders namely .bin and .require

3)now i execute 
    browserify main.js -o bundle.js
4)Add the following tag to my HTML file
    <script src='bundle.js'></script>



At Step 3 itself,i am getting the followng error

Error: Parsing file C:\Users\myfolder\projects\QRCode\main.js
: Unexpected token (1:0)
    at Deps.parseDeps (C:\Users\myfolder\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_mod
ules\browserify\node_modules\module-deps\index.js:439:28)
    at fromSource (C:\Users\myfolder\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
\browserify\node_modules\module-deps\index.js:378:44)
    at C:\Users\myfolder\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\browserify\
node_modules\module-deps\index.js:372:17
    at ConcatStream.<anonymous> (C:\Users\myfolder\AppData\Roaming\np
m\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\concat-stream\index.js:36:43)
    at emitNone (events.js:72:20)
    at ConcatStream.emit (events.js:166:7)
    at finishMaybe (C:\Users\myfolder\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_module
s\browserify\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:509:14)
    at endWritable (C:\Users\myfolder\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_module
s\browserify\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:519:3)
    at ConcatStream.Writable.end (C:\Users\myfolder\AppData\Roaming\n
pm\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:
484:5)
    at DuplexWrapper.onend (C:\Users\myfolder\AppData\Roaming\npm\nod
e_modules\browserify\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:543:10
)


btw this is the code of my main.js library:-

    <script type='text/jsx'>
    var React = require('react');
    var QRCode = require('qrcode.react');

    React.render(
      <QRCode value="http://facebook.github.io/react/" />,
      mountNode
    );
    </script>

tx in advance
```